# Calculating the value of arctan(x) in C++

Tags: c++

I have to calculate the value of `arctan(x)` . I have calculated the value of this by evaluating the following series :

> Arctan (x) = x – x^3/3 + x^5/5 – x^7/7 + x^9/9 - …

But the following code can not calculate the actual value. For example, `calculate_angle(1)` returns 38.34 . Why?

```
const double DEGREES_PER_RADIAN = 57.296;

double calculate_angle(double x)
{
    int power=5,count=3;
    double term,result,prev_res;

    prev_res = x;
    result= x-pow(x,3)/3;

    while(abs(result-prev_res)<1e-10)
    {
        term = pow(x,power)/power;
        if(count%2==0)
            term = term*(-1);
        prev_res=result;
        result=result+term;
        ++count;
        power+=2;
       // if(count=99)
         //   break;
    }

    return result*DEGREES_PER_RADIAN;
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if 38.34 is just what the Taylor Series gives you. This one grows pretty quickly.

Comment: What to do if I want to get the value of arc_tan(1) = 45 degree ??

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the Taylor series of this function 1. isn't convergent if `|x| >> 0`, furthermore [Wolframalpha suggests](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=taylor-expand+arctan%28x%29) that the series is different for `|x| < 1` and `|x| > 1`.

Comment: Then how can I find the value of arctan(x) without using standard library ?

Comment: @OcenaPothik, That sounds like an extremely pointless question, to be quite honest. ["How do I do X without using the function designed to do X?"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/02/06/10391383.aspx)

Comment: I want to find the value of arctan(x) . Can you give me a way for this ? Then you can delete the question .

Comment: @chris: Having just written `float cos(float)`, I disagree. The poster may be lacking a standard library too.

Comment: @MSalters, Well at least say "because the standard library function is not available" then. I don't imagine that situation is *too* common.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: I found the culprit. You forgot to include `stdlib.h`, where the function `abs` resides. You must have ignored the warning about `abs` being implicitly declared. I checked that removing the include yields the result 38.19 and including it yields the result ~45.

The compiler is not required to stop compilation when an undeclared function is being used (in this case abs). Instead, it is allowed to make assumptions on how the function is declared (in this case, wrong one.)

Besides, like other posters already stated, your use of `abs` is inappropriate as it returns an int, not a double or float. The condition in the while should be `>1e-100` not `<1e-100`. The `1e-100` is also too small.

--

You forgot to increase `count` and `power` after calculating the first two summands:

```
prev_res = x;
result= x-pow(x,3)/3;

count = 4; <<<<<<
power = 5; <<<<<<

while(abs(result-prev_res)<1e-100)
{
    term = pow(x,power)/power;
    if(count%2==1)
        term = term*(-1);
```

Also I consider your use of the `count` variable counterintuitive: it is intialized with `3` like if it denotes the last used power; but then, loop iterations increase it by `1` instead of `2` and you decide the sign by `count%2 == 1` as opposed to `power%4 == 3`

Comment: @OcenaPothik well, you increase it in the loop. Is that the only place where you need to increase it?

Comment: it denotes the no of term .For example, if count = 3 , then I want to determine whether the 3rd term has positive of negative sign ?

Comment: @OcenaPothik oh okay. In that the case the bug is that you use `count%2 == 1` where you should use `count%2 == 0`

Comment: I get the value of arctan(1) = 38.1973 . Why ?

Comment: @OcenaPothik I found out the culprit, see answer

Comment: `<stdlib.h>` is not the culprit. `abs` itself is. It is a function receiving an `int` and returning an `int`. It will not work here at all.

Comment: @n.m. declaring `int abs(double);` gives me the same result 38.19 as leaving out `stdlib.h`

Comment: You cannot just declare `abs` and hope it will magically return the type you want, declarations don't work this way. Besides, this is not the only bug.

Comment: Sorry my bad. *If* this is indeed C++ *and* there is `using namespace std` somewhere in the program, then `abs` will work too. However as I said this is not the only problem here.

Answer (score 3):

The series converges to tan^{-1} x, but not very fast.  Consider the series when `x=1`:

```
1 - 1/3 + 1/5 - 1/7 + 1/9 - ...
```

What is the error when truncating at the `1/9` term?  It's around `1/9`. To get `10^{-100}` accuracy, you would need to have `10^{100}` terms. The universe would end before you'd get that.  And, catastrophic round-off error and truncation error would make the answer utterly unreliable. You only have 14 digits to play with for `double`s.

Look at reference works like Abramowitz and Stegun [AMS 55] or the new NIST Digital Library of Mathematical Functions at http://dlmf.nist.gov to see how these are done in practice. Often, one uses Padé approximants instead of Taylor series. Even when you stick with Taylor series, you often use Chebyshev approximation to cut down on the total error.

I also recommend Numerical Methods that [Usually] Work, by Forman Acton.  Or the Numerical Recipes in ... series.

Comment: I can find easily the value of arctan(x) by functions from standard library . What procedure is followed there to find value ??

Comment: Why don't you go look at an implementation?

Comment: I don't know.  You could try looking at your platform's documentation.  These are usually done at low-level with hardware support; your computer's FPU may have routines that help.

Answer (score 2):

Your sign is the wrong way around after the first two terms. It should be:

```
if(count%2==0)
  term = term*(-1);
```

Your comparison is the wrong way around in the while condition. Also, you're expecting an unrealistically high level of precision. I would suggest something more like this:

```
while(fabs(result-prev_res)>1e-8)
```

Finally, you'll get a more accurate result with a better value for `DEGREES_PER_RADIAN`. Why not something like this:

```
const double DEGREES_PER_RADIAN = 180/M_PI;
```

Comment: I have followed your advice . But I have get the same value as before like arctan(1) = 38.1973 . Why ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention the need for `fabs` rather than `abs` in the while condition as shown above. The `abs` function is going to give you an integer result which is obviously useless here.